# SQL Select query rows using explode on a string

Tags: sql, select, subquery, mariadb

I need to query a MariaDB-database based on what ID is contained inside one column of a row. The ID's in the column '*children*' is a string with concatenated numbers like this:

```
123;32523;436;241;345;234;
```

... or:

```
23;45;324;56;2141;5464;2342;
```

I need a query, something like this:

```
Select * from testTbl WHERE ID in (Explode(";", Select children from testTbl WHERE ID = 1))
```

I need the query to return the rows inside the *children* column on row with ID = 1. What I am looking for is the equivalent to my hypothetical **Explode** command.

Comment: Well this is a good opportunity to understand database normalization

Comment: @Mihai Yes, but changing the structure of the database is not an option, I am just a "user" querying it :(

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: @Mihai Yes, ID and one more column is primary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not store lists of things as delimited lists.  Here are some reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Ids should have foreign key relationships to the tables they refer to.
- A column should contain a single item of information, not a list.
- SQL has this great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a "table".

That said, sometimes you are stuck with other people's really bad designs.  If so, you can do what you want with `replace()` and `find_in_set()`:

```
select t.*
from testtbl t2
where exists (select 1
              from testtbl t2
              where t2.id = 1 and
                    find_in_set(t.id, replace(t2.children, ';', ',')) > 0
             );
```

Comment: AND id=1 might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select *
from testTbl 
WHERE ';' + (Select children from testTbl WHERE ID = 1) + ';' LIKE '%;' + CAST(ID AS varchar(20)) + ';%'
```

Comment: From the look of it, it seemed promising but got the following Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+ CAST(ID AS varchar(20)) + ';%' LIMIT 0, 30'

Comment: I actually missed the "MariaDB" tag, and just assume SQL server. Maybe that's why you get a syntax error. The general idea should still be usuable though, if you can change it to valid MariaDB syntax.
However, looking at Gordon Linoff's answer, MariaDB has some built in functionality for it so you don't need the LIKE workaround.